# Powershell Script to Monitor Folder Space

Tags: powershell

I have written a script which monitors specific folder space monitoring and it alerts me once it crosses the threshold. Issue what i am facing is with multiple servers in place i am getting multiple emails so is it possible that we can consolidate the results in one mail having all servers which having issue. Below is script:-

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\server.txt
$folder = "D$\store\"
$smtpserver = "XXXXXX"
@( 
           foreach ($Server in $Servers) 
          { 
$folderSize = ( Get-ChildItem -path \\$server\$folder -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum ).Sum

if ($folderSize -gt '60Gb') {
 Write-output "Folder size exceeded 60 GB on server:-$Server. Current size on $server is $folderSize. Please review and take further action." | Out-file -FilePath "C:\reslt.txt"
 Send-MailMessage -to abc@abc.com -from xx@xx.com -Subject "Limit Alert" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Attachments "C:\reslt.txt"
 }

else { Write-output "Folder size is within 60GB on $server." }})
```

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to instead of writing output to a text file and sending it in the foreach loop, create a bunch of results, and then build your text file and send it after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post what you've tried.  That being said, here's a start, written in notepad, so excuse any slight issues.  You should probably just take results and instead of iterating over them, make them into a table, set the email to be HTML, and put the result of the table converted into an HTML snippet into the body of the message.

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\server.txt
$folder = "D$\store\"
$smtpserver = "XXXXXX"
$results = @()

foreach ($Server in $Servers) { 
    $folderSize = ( Get-ChildItem -path \\$server\$folder -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum ).Sum
    if ($folderSize -gt '60Gb') {
        Write-Output "Folder size exceeded limit on $server"
        $results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            ServerName = $Server
            FolderSize = $folderSize
        }
    }
    else { Write-output "Folder size is within 60GB on $server." }
}
if ($results.Count -gt 0){
    $bodyString = "Servers over limit:"
    #I'd get fancy here and take $results, format it as a table, and then convert to HTML and put the snippet in the body...
    $results | % {$bodyString += "The server "+$_.ServerName+"is over the limit and is currently at "+$_.FolderSize+"GB`r`n"}
    Send-MailMessage -to abc@abc.com -from xx@xx.com -Subject "Limit Alert" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Body $bodyString
}
else {
    Send-MailMessage -to abc@abc.com -from xx@xx.com -Subject "Limit Alert - no results" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Body "No results were found for servers over the limit"
}
```

Comment: I edited the script for few correction and that worked for me. Thanks help.

Comment: I need a addition to the result section with environment name. As of now i am getting result like:-Store Folder Status on below Servers: 
 
Store Folder on server1 Exceeded 20 GB and is currently at 25.1130541330203 GB
  
Store Folder on server2 Exceeded 20 GB and is currently at 25.0478365654126 GB
Can it be possible to make output likeSegmentStore Folder Status on below Servers: 
1. Env1
Store Folder on server1 Exceeded 20 GB and is currently at 25.1130541330203 GB
  
 2.Env2 
Store Folder on server2 Exceeded 20 GB and is currently at 25.0478365654126 GB